# NestJS on EC2 keeps responding with 502 randomly

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nestjs

I made a server with NestJS and ran it on an EC2 instance, and it is responding with 502 randomly.

I googled and a lot of articles mentioned the difference between the timeout interval of ALB and the server.

when I made a simple webpage server with express the same issue happened but fixed it by adjusting keepAliveTimeout and headersTimeout.
(each value was 65000ms and 67000ms)

however, this nestjs server still responds with 502 and I don't know what else to do.
tried to change the timeout of ALB to 30sec and to 120sec and this didn't work either.

what else is the possibility of this issue? I am lost.